# Custom level of logging with winston and morgan

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, winston

I have winston and added morgan to the logger system. I'm trying to add a separate logger for morgans api calls this way when I get an api call i get a diff output than a regular info and I also want to add the api calls to another file. How can I do that? I've seen online where they recommend creating another level, but I want to use winstons default levels and in addition add an api one.

Here's what I have:

```
const winston = require('winston');

const logger = winston.createLogger({
    level: winston.config.syslog.levels,
    format: winston.format.combine(
        winston.format.timestamp({ format: 'h:mm:ss a YYYY-MM-DD' }),
        winston.format.errors({ stack: true }),
        winston.format.splat(),
        winston.format.json()
    ),
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'logger/info.log' }),
        new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'logger/error.log', level: 'error' }),
    ],
    exceptionHandlers: [new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'logger/exceptions.log' })],
    rejectionHandlers: [new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'logger/rejections.log' })],
});


if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    logger.add(
        new winston.transports.Console({
            level: 'debug',
            handleExceptions: true,
            json: false,
            colorize: true,
            format: winston.format.combine(
                winston.format.colorize({ message: true, level: true }),
                winston.format.combine(winston.format.printf((info) => `${info.level} - ${info.timestamp}: ${info.message}`))
            ),
        })
    );
}

module.exports = logger;
```